# 25 Sidekiq processes for Gitlab

Tags: debian, git, gitlab, htop

Looking at `htop` output on my server I see 25 sidekiq processes spawned by Gitlab. I use Gitlab privately, so there is never going to be any load, so I doubt all of those processes are required, but I cannot see how to configure their number.

Is there actually any point for me to bother about that on a resource-restricted server?

Comment: Did you solved this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No, I'm afraid I left it be the way it is. Mostly because I couldn't figure out how to set the sidekiq config for gitlab like @md_5 suggested in his answer.

Comment: I solved my memory issue (Gitlab & Node.js) by increasing the swap, but I still have the 25 Sidekiq processes there, so if there is any advances, I'd be happy to know.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, check this thread here: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2780

Just edit the sidekiq config.yml, note the concurrency option: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/config.yml

Comment: Hi, I'm also using Gitlab, and as of version 6.7.3 there is no config file that I know of specifically for Sidekiq. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

I edited the Sidekiq startup arguments. In GitLab <7.0.0 it's under `scripts/background_jobs` but in >7.0.0 it's under `bin/background_jobs`

**Change:**

```
function start_sidekiq
{
  bundle exec sidekiq -q post_receive -q mailer -q system_hook -q project_web_hook -q gitlab_shell -q common -q default -e $RAILS_ENV -P $sidekiq_pidfile $@ >> $sidekiq_logfile 2>&1
}
```

**To:**

```
function start_sidekiq
{
  bundle exec sidekiq -c 10 -q post_receive -q mailer -q system_hook -q project_web_hook -q gitlab_shell -q common -q default -e $RAILS_ENV -P $sidekiq_pidfile $@ >> $sidekiq_logfile 2>&1
}
```

Notice the `-c 10`. Change that to whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

In Debian install of version 9.3.0 I had `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` which have configuration lines for sidekiq.

Change

```
# sidekiq['concurrency'] = 25
```

to whatever number you seem fit:

```
sidekiq['concurrency'] = 5
```

(Reason I changed my self was because the default 25 processes ate a lot of ram causing swap to be used, in turn making gitlab real slow. Performance improved alot for me after this change)

Comment: Yep. This is the way to go! Don't forget to run: `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. Any reason why you selected 5?

Comment: thanks. Then it's puma showing up all the threads. Is there a general config value that rules them all?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the proposed solutions to this problem both in this Q&A thread and elsewhere on line seem to be out of date, but the *problem* is still current, so here is my solution for Gitlab 9.5.3 on Archlinux using the community packages:

I was unable to get this to work by adding a `sidekick.yml`, `sidekick_queues.yml`, or to anything else in /etc and resorted to hacking the installed package source directly.

Edit the system file `/usr/share/webapps/gitlab/config/sidekiq_queues.yml` and add this line just after the opening `---` YAML marker:

```
:concurrency: 5
```

The resulting YAML looks something like this:

[image: selection_414]

Then `sudo systemctl restart gitlab-sidekiq` and I finally got only 5 threads chewing through memory instead of 25.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to just go to `/home/git/gitlab/config`. There was a `sidekiq.yml.example` file. I just ran:

```
$ cd /home/git/gitlab/config
$ cp sidekiq.yml.example sidekiq.yml
```

Using `vim sidekiq.yml` you will see that there is a `:concurrency:` option. Set it to the number of sidekiq processes you wish, save the file, and run `service gitlab restart`.

Disclaimer: Location of your GitLab installation folder may vary. For me it was `/home/git/gitlab`

Answer (score 0):

I have a "from source" installed gitlab version and I had to edit `config/sidekiq_queues.yml` and add `:concurrency: X` (where X is your desired number of processes.

The `sidekiq.yml` is not used by gitlab. You can see that if you look at the running process and its -C option.